# Bad effect on fade in/out transitions when mouse enters or leaves

Tags: javafx

When I enter or leave the node very quick, the fade restarts or somethin like this making the effect look bad. I searched for some solution on this but I can't find anything. Do you know how can I do a fade in and out effect when the mouse enters or leave the node without that restart on animation?

```
    //Fade In configuration
    fadeIn = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(200));
    fadeIn.setFromValue(1);
    fadeIn.setToValue(0.5);
    fadeIn.setCycleCount(1);
    fadeIn.setAutoReverse(true);

    //Fade Out configurqation
    fadeOut = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(100));
    fadeOut.setFromValue(0.5);
    fadeOut.setToValue(1);
    fadeOut.setCycleCount(1);
    fadeOut.setAutoReverse(true);
```

When I enter or leave the node with the mouse, the animation looks bad.
I want to have a smooth fade in/out.

Comment: See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Just curious, but what happens if you get rid of the `setAutoReverse`?

Comment: Nothing since I had the cycle number set to 1

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use the same `FadeTransition` for both the fade-in and the fade-out animations. When the mouse exits the `Node` you need reverse the animation by setting the `rate` property to a negative number. If you wanted to reverse at the same speed, you would set the value to `-1.0`; however, since you want to fade out in half the time it takes to fade in, you should set the value to `-2.0`. Here's an example:

```
import javafx.animation.FadeTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(100.0, 100.0);
        rect.setOpacity(0.5);

        FadeTransition animation = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(200.0), rect);
        animation.setFromValue(0.5);
        animation.setToValue(1.0);

        rect.setOnMouseEntered(event -> {
            animation.setRate(1.0);
            animation.play();
        });
        rect.setOnMouseExited(event -> {
            animation.setRate(-2.0);
            animation.play();
        });

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new StackPane(rect), 500.0, 300.0));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

Comment: This works perfect. Didn't thought about using the same FadeTansition. Thank you!